# Expect is not a function in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm learning unit test in react from freecodecamp blog. I followed all the steps mentioned in that for testing a DOM Element in the react app but test fails by saying the following message:

```
PASS  src/App.test.js
 FAIL  src/components/TestElements.test.js
  Testing of DOM Element › should equal to 0

    TypeError: expect(...).toHaveTextContent is not a function

       8 |     it('should equal to 0', () => {
       9 |         const { getByTestId } = render(<TestElements />);
    > 10 |         expect(getByTestId('counter')).toHaveTextContent(0)
         |                                        ^
      11 |        });
      12 |
      13 |     it('should test button disbaled status',()=>{

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/TestElements.test.js:10:40)
```

Hers is my TestElement.js

```
import React from 'react'

const TestElements = () => {
 const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0)
  
 return (
  <>
    <h1 data-testid="counter">{ counter }</h1>
    <button data-testid="button-up" onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}> Up</button>
    <button disabled data-testid="button-down" onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}>Down</button>
 </>
    )
  }
  
  export default TestElements
```

And here is my TestElements.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {render,cleanup} from '@testing-library/react'
import TestElements from './TestElements'

describe('Testing of DOM Element', ()=>{
    
    afterEach(cleanup)
    it('should equal to 0', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<TestElements />); 
        expect(getByTestId('counter')).toHaveTextContent(0)
       });

    it('should test button disbaled status',()=>{
        const {getByTestId} = render(<TestElements/>)
        expect(getByTestId('button-down')).toBeDisabled()

    })
    it('should test button is not disabled status', ()=>{
        const {getByTestId} = render(<TestElements/>)
        expect(getByTestId('button-up')).not.toHaveAttribute('disabled')
        
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you have a `jest config` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import `extend-expect` from `@testing-library/jest-dom` in your test file like this:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

or if you don't want to import above line in every test file you need to add a `jest config` to your project like this:

Create a `jest.config.js` file in the `root` of your project and then put this code in it:

```
//<====This is jest.config.js====>
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"]
}
```

and then create a `setupTests.js` at the `root` of the project and put this code in it:

```
//<===== this is setupTests.js =====>
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

Comment: Thank you @Taghi Khavari

Comment: I have a doubt here. It work just fine for App.js without importing the above statement

Comment: what is your `App.js` test file?

Comment: Did you use `toHaveTextContent` in the `App test file` too?

Comment: No i did not used . Here is my App.test.js file codes

Comment: import React from 'react'
import {render,cleanup} from '@testing-library/react'
import App from './App.js'


describe('Taking a screenshot of the the renderd App', ()=>{
    afterEach(cleanup)
    let { asFragment } = render(<App />)
    it('should take screen shot of App that rendered',()=>{
        expect(asFragment(<App />)).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
   
})

Comment: So that's because you're not getting any error in your `App.test.js` file and you're getting the error in the `TestElements.test.js`. `jest expect` has some `built in` `Matcher functions` like `expect(something).toBe(something)` but `toHaveTextContent` is not `builtin` `matcher` so you need to `extend expect matchers`