# expect is not defined in jest-dom

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I get the following error on running `npm test` on my project, not created with `create-react-app`:

```
ReferenceError: expect is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ryedida/Desktop/threaded-messenger/node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/dist/extend-expect.js:7:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1256:30)
...
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ryedida/Desktop/threaded-messenger/src/componentTestUtils.js:1:1)
```

### Setup

My root directory has a `jest.config.js` file, whose contents are

```
const config = {
    verbose: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/componentTestUtils.js'],
    testEnvironment: "jsdom"
};

module.exports = config;
```

`componentTestUtils.js` has

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../components/App';
```

and defines some functions that I use. I am using Node 14.7, npm 7.6.3, `@testing-library/jest-dom` 5.12.0, `@testing-library/react` 11.2.6. My `test` script in `package.json` is

```
mocha --require @babel/register --reporter progress components/*.test.js
```

### Similar Questions/Issues

My research in this issue has led me to

- [this GitHub issue in Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme-matchers/issues/86), where a highly voted answer essentially says add the `setupFilesAfterEnv` key in the jest config
- [this GitHub issue in jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/122), where the recommendations to upgrade `@testing-library/jest-dom` and `@testing-library/react` don't apply since my versions are higher, and their recommendation to upgrade from Node 10 to 12 also doesn't apply. Their other recommendation to add the same key above also did not work.
- [this GitHub issue in jest-native](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native/issues/46), the same `setupFilesAfterEnv` recommendation
- [this SO question with the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541311/expect-is-not-a-function-in-react-testing-library), but I already have the import in the accepted answer.

How do I solve this error?

Comment: If you are using jest library, shouldn't your test script start with jest too?

Comment: D'oh. You're right. I did away with the mocha stuff and changed it to just `jest components/*.test.js`.

Comment: Have you found a solution for it?